# Using Symfony php framework for uploading file

Tags: file-upload

I'm developing a software using Symfony framework. This software contains two part: back end(server side) and front end(client side). In front end using a angular framework for UI and not using a twig (twig is a symfony UI framework). In back end me should create API for using a Front end .

Now:
user upload file in front end and using a post method for sending a file in back end. I should create a controller for post method (this is not problem). The problem that occuring is I want to get file with symfony framework.
I search in the web and read all things about upload file with symfony, but all of them using twig and not using a raw API. 
Can any body tell me, how to get post data with symfony?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very understandable.

You will find in the official documentation:

- [a cookbook about handling file upload with Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html)
- how to handle Post data from a form (can't post more than two links in my answer, but look at the Form chapter of the doc, and search more specifically about $form->getData() method)
- [how to manage Post data in a less specific context](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#the-request-object).

Hope it will help.